# How to Turn All Bold Text in post content into h2 or h3 tag using css?

Tags: css, text, bold

How can I turn all bold text in a post's content to a `h2` or `h3` tag using CSS?

I can change the color of bold text in a WordPress post to red, but I also want to make (only) the bold text in the WordPress post into `h2` or `h3`.

```
b, strong {
   color: red;}
```

if there is any other way like from functions.php or else, please share, basically i have more than 1000 pages and want a quick fiz to turn all the bold text in post into h2.

Comment: can you show content in html you are used ?

Comment: You can't change the semantics of html with css.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot do this in CSS.  Tags are assigned in HTML---In CSS you can only edit the format of these tags.

One simple solution is to create a class or a few classes which all contain the format for boldness, the color you want, etc. and assign all the H2 and H3 tags in HTML to the respective classes you created.